# Problems with `PUT` FTP command under WSL2 (via VPN)

Tags: ftp, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm experiencing problems with FTP under WSL2 while trying to transfer a HTML file to an FTP server running under IIS 10.

After issuing a `PUT` command it gets stuck on *"Waiting for transfer to complete"* for a few minutes and then it outputs *"425 Data channel timed out due to not meeting the minimum bandwidth requirement."*

For some reason the same script works fine under WSL1.

Here's an example FTP session:

```
user-name@DESKTOP:~/$ ftp -p
ftp> open
(to) my-ftp-server.com
Connected to my-ftp-server.com.
220 Microsoft FTP Service
Name (my-ftp-server.com:user-name): my-ftp-server.com|remote-ftp-user
331 Password required
Password:
230 User logged in.
Remote system type is Windows_NT.
ftp> dir
227 Entering Passive Mode (10,150,1,82,213,210).
125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.
226 Transfer complete.
ftp> lcd _site
Local directory now /home/user-name/_site
ftp> put index.html
local: index.html remote: index.html
227 Entering Passive Mode (10,150,1,82,213,212).
125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.
425 Data channel timed out due to not meeting the minimum bandwidth requirement.
23114 bytes sent in 0.00 secs (145.0212 MB/s)
```

Also the FTP server on IIS locks the file being transferred and needs to be killed via Task Manager (cant be stopped via "Services") on order to make another attempt.

### Wireshark analyis

I've captured packages exchanged between WSL and FTP Server for both WSL1 and WSL2. The message sequence is identical, meaning there might be nothing wrong with FTP client / server.

### VPN Client

I'm suspecting that this has something to do with the fact that the FTP server is reached via VPN, while VPN client (FortiClient) is running on the host Windows machine. Since WSL2 uses it's own virtual network adapter Windows needs to do NAT. For some reason a return message "Transfer completed" is dropped along the way making the FTP client wait until timeout.

Comment: Is it WSL1 vs. WSL2 on the same or on different machines? If different machines, then it's probably a firewall issue.

Comment: Yes - WSL1 and WSL2 both sit on the same machine. The FTP server is reached via VPN (I'm working remote due Corona virus). What's even stranger is that WSL2 running on a machine at the office doesn't have this problem. It's not a firewall issue - I've turned it off.